# Recalculate X and Y Coordinates From New Screensize

Tags: java, swing, resize, awt, graphics2d

I'm trying to display tiles from an array I have so that they always fill the size of the screen when drawn together.  I am ignoring aspect ratio for now.

Here's how my code works.  I have tile objects that are passed on to a tileset (class for managing an array of tile objects), and then I iterate through the tileset array, returning each tile object id and rendering a subimage of my tileset image based on said ids.

Here's my mapUpdate method, which is called on every JFrame resize event:

```
public synchronized void mapUpdate(Screen screen) {
    factorX = (float)(screen.getWidth() / scW);
    factorY = (float)(screen.getHeight() / scH);

    for (int i = 0; i < tileset.getRows(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tileset.getCols(); j++) {
            int x = tileset.getTile(i, j).getX();
            int y = tileset.getTile(i, j).getY();
            tileset.getTile(i, j).setX((int)(x * factorX));
            tileset.getTile(i, j).setY((int)(y * factorY));
        }
    }

    mapTiles.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i * 70 < mapImage.getWidth(); i++) {
        mapTiles.add(mapImage.getSubimage(70 * i, 0, 70, 70).getScaledInstance(screen.getWidth() / 10, screen.getHeight() / 10, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
    }
}
```

mapTiles is an ArrayList of Images, and on each resize event it resets the arraylist, scales my subimages to 1/10th width and height, and then re-adds the newly sized images for me to pull out for rendering (the tileset image is only 3 tiles with an original size of 70x70).

And here is the componentResized method if you were curious:

```
public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
    canvas.setSize(app.getContentPane().getWidth(), app.getContentPane().getHeight());
    if (level1 != null) {
        level1.mapUpdate(this);
    }
}
```

As you can see in my mapUpdate method, I attempt to get a float to multiply each current x and y value by to receive the new correct values (it will round the integers), but this doesn't work at all.

Is there any solution to easily re-calculate my X and Y coordinates so that the tiles are drawn correctly?

Comment: Unless you're using a `null` layout there should be no need to set the size of the component, assuming `canvas` is a component

Comment: Change `(float)(screen.getWidth() / scW)` to `screen.getWidth() / (float)scW` which should remove the integer truncation which is occurring currently

Comment: Also beware, `componentResized` can be called a number of times in quick succession, you really don't want to be doing anything in there which is time consuming as it will cause lag in the re-rendering process of your UI, better to invalidate any caches and rebuild them on the next update

Comment: Pixels cannot be float values, that's why truncation is necessary.  I'm aware that componentResized can be called very quickly, which is part of my issue in trying to figure things out.

Comment: Also, even after changing the factorX and factorY to floats, either the algorithm itself or the general truncation is causing rendering issues.  The tiles do not stay by themselves as expected, but rather separate from one another.

Comment: Then why are you trying to use floats?  What you should be doing is calculating the "best" x/y position to start from and the increment the x/y position by a known factor (ie the size of each tile), that way, they won't "float" apart

Comment: That's what I've attempted to do.  My factorX and factorY are based on the original dimensions of the screen (640 x 480)

Comment: No, you're trying to "move" by the factor.  I'm suggesting that you calculate your x/y anchor position which would give you the "origin" point and then move by an exact amount, which would be the size of each cell.  The "factor" is providing your code with the opportunity to introduce varience between each point

Comment: Oh my.  You're a legend @MadProgrammer !! Thanks!

Comment: :) More crazy then legendary. Feel free to provide your own answer with the solution you've used

Answer (score 1):

Your factorX should not be a float. It should be an int. If you use a float you will get rounding, so occasionally you will have a pixel gap between tiles because of rounding. If you just use an int then you don't have to worry about this. Then the location is just the factor * the index value of the for loop.

On the other hand the easiest solution is to just use a JPanel with a GridLayout. Then you can add a JLabel with an Image icon. The GridLayout will resize each component equally.

You can then even use the [Stretch Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/) and the images will be dynamically resized as the frame is resized.

Comment: You've got to be kidding me.  That's a thing..?  I should have known about this GridLayout lol.  Thanks...

Comment: @user3059686, see the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for information on GridLayout and the other layout managers.

Comment: Ah, I've just realized.  I don't believe the GridLayout solution will work, as this game will be a scrolling platformer and thus the tiles will need to be scrollable (which means that the grids being displayed shouldn't always be identical dimensions).

Comment: @user3059686, then you can check out the `GridBagLayout`. Each cell can be a different size.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION courtesy of @MadProgrammer - The solution was to simply calculate the new X and Y "origins" for each tile.  I still need to implement adjusting the position for tiles that have moved based on the newly calculated origins, but this solution works for tiles that do not move (again, simply recalculate the X and Y origin positions).

```
public synchronized void mapUpdate(Screen screen) {
    int originX = screen.getWidth() / 10;
    int originY = screen.getHeight() / 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < tileset.getRows(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tileset.getCols(); j++) {
            tileset.getTile(i, j).setX((originX * j));
            tileset.getTile(i, j).setY((originY * i));
        }
    }

    mapTiles.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i * 70 < mapImage.getWidth(); i++) {
        mapTiles.add(mapImage.getSubimage(70 * i, 0, 70, 70).getScaledInstance(screen.getWidth() / 10, screen.getHeight() / 10, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
    }
}
```